# How to sort search dictionary result based on frequency in j2me

Tags: java-me, dictionary, midp, prediction, n-gram

This is my dictionary format:

> word      Frequency
>
> Gone     60
>
> Goes     10
>
> Go       30

So far the system returns words eg starting with 'g' as go30, goes10, gone60  as a list.
(alphabetically). I want to increase the accuracy of the system so that the search result is based on frequency. Words with high frequencies appear first. kindly help.

Here is the Text midlet class that reads the dictionary line by line.

```
      public class Text extends MIDlet {
     // Fields 

private static final String[] DEFAULT_KEY_CODES = {
    // 1
    ".,?!'\"1-()@/:_",
    // 2
    "ABC2",
    // 3
    "DEF3",
    // 4
    "GHI4",
    // 5
    "JKL5",
    // 6
    "MNO6",
    // 7
    "PQRS7",
    // 8
    "TUV8",
    // 9
    "WXYZ9",
};

//Initializing inner Classes
public ComposeText() {
    cmdHandler = new CommandHandler();
    lineVector = new Vector();
}

//Calling All InitMethods, setting Theme, Show MainForm
public void startApp() {
    Display.init(this);
    setTheme();
    initCmd();
    initMainGui();
    mainFrm.show();
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

//Initializing all the Commands
public void initCmd() {
    exitCmd = new Command("Exit");
    selectCmd = new Command("Ok");
    cancelCmd = new Command("Cancel");
    predCmd = new Command("Prediction");
    sendCmd = new Command("Send");

    tfPredArea = new TextField();

         //check dictionary
    try {
            readFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}

//Initiating MainScreen
public void initMainGui() {
    mainFrm = new Form("Compose Text");
    mainFrm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainFrm.setLayout(new CoordinateLayout(150, 150));
    mainFrm.addCommand(exitCmd);
    mainFrm.addCommand(predCmd);
    mainFrm.addCommand(sendCmd);
    mainFrm.addCommandListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(ae.getSource() == predCmd){
                            initPredGui();
            } else if(ae.getSource() == exitCmd){
            destroyApp(true);
            notifyDestroyed();
            }
        }
    });
    // To : 07xxxxxxxxxx
    Dimension d1 = new Dimension(130, 20);
    lbTo = new Label("To:");
    lbTo.setX(10);
    lbTo.setY(10);
    tfTo = new TextField();
    tfTo.setReplaceMenu(false);
    tfTo.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);
    tfTo.setInputModeOrder(new String[]{"123"});
    tfTo.setMaxSize(13);
    tfTo.setX(40);
    tfTo.setY(10);
    tfTo.setPreferredSize(d1);

    //Message : Compose Text
    Dimension d2 = new Dimension(135, 135);
    lbSms = new Label("Message:");
    lbSms.setX(5);
    lbSms.setY(40);
    tfSms = new TextField();
    tfSms.setReplaceMenu(false);
    tfSms.setX(40);
    tfSms.setY(40);
    tfSms.setPreferredSize(d2);

    //add stuff
    mainFrm.addComponent(lbTo);
    mainFrm.addComponent(lbSms);
    mainFrm.addComponent(tfTo);
    mainFrm.addComponent(tfSms);
  }
  //Initiating FilterSelection Screen
  public void initPredGui() {
    predForm = new Form("Prediction on");           
    predForm.setLayout(new CoordinateLayout(150, 150));
    predForm.addCommand(cancelCmd);
    predForm.addCommand(selectCmd);

    //textfied in prediction form
    final Dimension d5 = new Dimension(200, 200);
    tfPredArea = new TextField();
    tfPredArea.setReplaceMenu(false);
    tfPredArea.setX(10);
    tfPredArea.setY(10);
    tfPredArea.setPreferredSize(d5);

    predForm.addComponent(tfPredArea);

    final ListModel underlyingModel = new DefaultListModel(lineVector);
  //        final ListModel underlyingModel = new           

  DefaultListModel(tree.getAllPrefixMatches(avail));

  // this is a list model that can narrow down the underlying model
    final SortListModel proxyModel = new SortListModel(underlyingModel);

    final List suggestion = new List(proxyModel);


    tfPredArea.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {

        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {

            int len = 0;
            int i = 0;
            String input = tfPredArea.getText();
            len = tfPredArea.getText().length();

            //ensure start search character is set for each word 
            if (!(len == 0)) {
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        k = i;
                    }     
                }
                String currentInput = input.substring(k + 1, len);
                proxyModel.filter(currentInput);

            }
        }
        });

        Dimension d3 = new Dimension(110, 120);
        suggestion.setX(80);
        suggestion.setY(80);
        suggestion.setPreferredSize(d3);

        predForm.addComponent(suggestion);

        suggestion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    String string = suggestion.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (tfPredArea.getText().charAt(0) == 0) {
                    tfPredArea.setText(string);
                }
               else if (tfPredArea.getText().length() == 0) {
                    tfPredArea.setText(string);
                } else {
                    tfPredArea.setText(tfPredArea.getText() + string);
                }

            }
    });
        predForm.addCommandListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getSource() == addCmd) {
                newDictionaryFrm.show();
            } else {
                mainFrm.show();
            }
        }
    });
         predForm.show();
   }

  //Setting Theme for All Forms
   public void setTheme() {
    try {
        Resources r = Resources.open("/theme.res");
        UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme(
                r.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't load the theme");
    }
  }

  //Inner class CommandHandler
  public class CommandHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //cancelCommand from predictionForm
        if (ae.getSource() == cancelCmd) {
            if (edit) {
                mainFrm.show();
    //                    clearFields();
            } else if (ae.getSource() == selectCmd){
                tfPredList.addDataChangeListener(model);
                predForm.show();
            }
            else{}
        }
    }
 }

 // method that reads dictionary line by line
 public void readFile() throws IOException {
    tree = new Trie();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Maa Corpus.txt-01-ngrams-Alpha.txt"));
    String line = null;
    // Read a single line from the file. null represents the EOF.
    while ((line = readLine(reader)) != null) {
        // Append to a vector to be used as a list
        lineVector.addElement(line);
    }
  }

  public String readLine(InputStreamReader reader) throws IOException {
    // Test whether the end of file has been reached. If so, return null.
    int readChar = reader.read();
    if (readChar == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer("");
    // Read until end of file or new line

    while (readChar != -1 && readChar != '\n') {
        // Append the read character to the string.
        // This is part of the newline character
        if (readChar != '\r') {
            string.append((char) readChar);
        }
        // Read the next character
        readChar = reader.read();
    }
    return string.toString();
 }
 }
}
```

The SortListModel Class has a filter method that gets prefix from the textfield datachangeLister

```
     class SortListModel implements ListModel, DataChangedListener {
   private ListModel underlying;
   private Vector filter;
   private Vector listeners = new Vector();
   public SortListModel(ListModel underlying) {
   this.underlying = underlying;
   underlying.addDataChangedListener(this);
  }

  private int getFilterOffset(int index) {
   if(filter == null) {
       return index;
   }
   if(filter.size() > index) {
       return ((Integer)filter.elementAt(index)).intValue();
   }
   return -1;
  }

 private int getUnderlyingOffset(int index) {
   if(filter == null) {
       return index;
   }
   return filter.indexOf(new Integer(index));
  }

   public void filter(String str) {
   filter = new Vector();
   str = str.toUpperCase();
   for(int iter = 0 ; iter < underlying.getSize() ; iter++) {
       String element = (String)underlying.getItemAt(iter);
       if(element.toUpperCase().startsWith(str)) // suggest only if smthing
       {
           filter.addElement(new Integer(iter));
       }
   }
   dataChanged(DataChangedListener.CHANGED, -1);
   }

  public Object getItemAt(int index) {
   return underlying.getItemAt(getFilterOffset(index));
  }

  public int getSize() {
    if(filter == null) {
       return underlying.getSize();
   }
   return filter.size();
 }

 public int getSelectedIndex() {
   return Math.max(0, getUnderlyingOffset(underlying.getSelectedIndex()));
  }

 public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
   underlying.setSelectedIndex(getFilterOffset(index));
 }

 public void addDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
   listeners.addElement(l);
 }

 public void removeDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
   listeners.removeElement(l);
}

  public void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
    underlying.addSelectionListener(l);
  }

  public void removeSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
   underlying.removeSelectionListener(l);
 }

 public void addItem(Object item) {
   underlying.addItem(item);
 }

 public void removeItem(int index) {
    underlying.removeItem(index);
  }

  public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
   if(index > -1) {
       index = getUnderlyingOffset(index);
       if(index < 0) {
           return;
       }
    }
    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < listeners.size() ; iter++) {

       ((DataChangedListener)listeners.elementAt(iter)).dataChanged(type, index);
    }
     }
  }
```

Comment: show the code that you're having problem with

Comment: @gnat Just needed some advise. I will provide the code though